# Excel (2016) recursive concatenation and hyperlinks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Excel sheet that calculates distance, speed and bearing of a boat given a waypoint in degree, minutes and seconds (I use it to follow races and friends). The sheet supports up to 5000 points. I want to add a column with a hyperlink to [www.windy.com](http://www.windy.com) to plot the points in windy website.

I already have a concatenated formula that create the hyperlink but I add every value by myself.

1st. =HIPERVINCULO(CONCATENAR("https://www.windy.com/distance/";U5;",";V5;";";U6;",";V6);"Windy")

2nd. =HIPERVINCULO(CONCATENAR("https://www.windy.com/distance/";U5;",";V5;";";U6;",";V6;";";U7;",";V7);"Windy")

3rd. =HIPERVINCULO(CONCATENAR("https://www.windy.com/distance/";U5;",";V5;";";U6;",";V6;";";U7;",";V7;";";U8;",";V8);"Windy")

4rd. =HIPERVINCULO(CONCATENAR("https://www.windy.com/distance/";U5;",";V5;";";U6;",";V6;";";U7;",";V7;";";U8;",";V8;";";U9;",";V9);"Windy") and so on

The link uses values in columns V and W because windy needs the values with decimal point instead decimal comma.

Here is the table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2W8n.png)

The problem that i'm facing is how to automaticaly/recursive add the points that are inserted. Now I add to the Concatenate/hyperlink formula the new point. But I would like to have a routine/algorithm to automatically do the concatenate in every row until the last one (row 5004).

Thanks a lot.

PS. If someone thinks that would like to have the excel sheet or find it usefull I can send a copy.

05.07.21 10:13

```
  Hi all, thanks Ron Rosenfeld and EEM for your answers. EEM the formula you gave me worked perfectly. Thanks a looot. I only had to do minor change. But now I'm facing a different problem. Sorry.
```

Problem now is the 255 chars hyperlink limit. After 15 iterations the formula doesn't work anymore and I only get #¡VALOR! #VALUE!.

I have been trying before asking again, but without luck. Seems to be a way to solve this "behaviour" with VBA but I can't figure out.

As Mr. Rosenfeld required more information, here are the formulas used.

[Table: image with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAv5D.jpg)

As you can see in column W there is a link with the growing formula I started with.
The formula provided by EEM is in column AA.

DECIMAL LATITUDE
ROWS L5:L5004   =IF(D5="","",IF(G5="S",(-1*(D5+E5/60+F5/3600)),(D5+E5/60+F5/3600)))

DECIMAL LONGITUDE
ROWS M5:M5004   =IF(H5="","",IF(K5="W",(-1*(H5+I5/60+J5/3600)),(H5+I5/60+J5/3600)))

[www.windy.com](http://www.windy.com) uses . as decimal separator instead ,

CHANGE Excel , to windy .

ROWS U5:U5004   =SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(L5,6),",",".")

ROWS V5:V5004   =SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(M5,7),",",".")

Formulas to create the hyperlink (A million thanks to EEM)

ROW AA5 = HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE( "https://www.windy.com/distance/", $X5, ",", $Y5 ),CONCATENATE( $X5, ",", $Y5 ) )

ROW AA6:AA5004 = IF(U6=0,"",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE( "https://www.windy.com/distance/", AA5, ";", $X6, ",", $Y6 ), CONCATENATE( AA5, ";", $X6, ",", $Y6 ) ))

As said, after 14 iterations the hyperlink grows more than 255 characters.

[www.windy.com](http://www.windy.com) format to create a route latitude, longitude;

https://www.windy.com/distance/20.31,-60.52;22.05,-61.36;23.03,-61.73;25.20,-61.10;26.17,-62.82;27.06,-62.62?22.973,-61.669,7

Formulas used to calculate distance and bearing (just in case someone needs them)

DISTANCE
=IF(L6="","",(6371*ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-L5))*COS(RADIANS(90-L6))+SIN(RADIANS(90-L5))*SIN(RADIANS(90-L6))*COS(RADIANS(M5-M6))))*0.539956)

BEARING
=IF(P6=0,"",IF(L6="","",DEGREES(MOD(ATAN2((COS(RADIANS(L5))*SIN(RADIANS(L6)))-(SIN(RADIANS(L5))*COS(RADIANS(L6))*COS(RADIANS(M6-M5))), SIN(RADIANS(M6-M5))*COS(RADIANS(L6))),2*PI()))))

Thanks everybody for your time and knowledge.

13.07.21. NO LUCK. I have been incapable of doing it. But I opened the file in OPEN OFFICE and with a little bit of formatting it's working flawlessly.

It's annoying the 255 chars limit in Excel, but I'm not going to break my head any more.

Thanks a lot EEm.

Comment: I suggest you do this in Power Query or VBA.  You can then create the string with the numbers formatted with dot rather than comma as decimal.  *Hard for me to tell exactly what you're doing with your formula since there are no column letters on your image; nor an example of what the output string should look like.*

Answer (score 2):

The formula proposed uses the `friendly_name` parameter of the [HYPERLINK function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f) to hold the accumulated concatenation of `latitud` and `longitud` of each row in order to be passed to the next row formula.
To Show the word `Windy` in the cell format the cells with this `Number Format`: `;;;"Wendy"`

1. Enter this formula in `[Y5]`:
   `= HIPERVINCULO(`
     `CONCATENAR( "https://www.windy.com/distance/"; $U5; ","; $V5 );`
     `CONCATENAR( $U5; ","; $V5 ) )`
2. Enter this formula in `[Y6]`:
   `= HIPERVINCULO(`
     `CONCATENAR( "https://www.windy.com/distance/"; Y5; ","; $U6; ","; $V6 );`
     `CONCATENAR( Y5; ","; $U6; ","; $V6 ) )`
3. Copy formula in `[Y6]` to `[Y7:Y5004]`
4. Format range `[Y5:Y5004]` with NumberFormat: `;;;"Wendy"`